# Parse CDATA from XML to enable editing Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, cdata

I am writing a simulator which communicates with a client's piece of software over a local socket. The communication language is XML. I have written some code which works - parsing the incoming XML string into Document via the DocumentBuilder interface.

I have been encountering a problem with CDATA (Having never seen it before). Basically, I need to access fields within the CDATA tag and change them. I load up a 'template' XML document (to reply to the messages with) and use values received in the first message inside the response. Some of the fields that need to be changed are in this CDATA tag (clear what I mean below).

```
public static String getOutputMessage(String input) throws Exception{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document inputDoc, outputDoc;
    Element messageElement = (Element)inputDoc.getElementsByTagName("TRANS").item(0);
    messageType = messageElement.getAttribute("name");
    if (messageType.equals("processTransaction")){
        outputDoc = db.parse(path+"processTransaction\\posPrintReceipt.xml");
        outputDoc = changeContent(outputDoc, "PAN_NUMBER", transaction.getPan_number());
        outputDoc = changeContent(outputDoc, "TOKEN", transaction.getToken());
        outputDoc = changeContent(outputDoc, "TOTAL_AMOUNT", transaction.getTotal_amount());
        outputDoc = changeContent(outputDoc, "TRANSACTION_TIME", transaction.getTransaction_time());
        outputDoc = changeContent(outputDoc, "TRANSACTION_DATE", transaction.getTransaction_date());
    }
}

private static Document changeContent(Document doc,String tag,String value) {
    System.out.println("Changing: ["+tag+" : "+value+"]");
    NodeList nodes=doc.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    Node node = nodes.item(0);
    Node parent=node.getParentNode();
    node.setTextContent(value);
    System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0) + " " + node.getTextContent());
    parent.replaceChild(node, doc.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0));
    return doc;
}
```

The functions above work on normal Elements but below is an example XML message I have to read and change some values such as

```
<RLSOLVE_MSG version="5.0">
<MESSAGE>
    <SOURCE_ID>DP01</SOURCE_ID>
    <TRANS_NUM>000001</TRANS_NUM>
</MESSAGE>
<POI_MSG type="interaction">
    <INTERACTION name="posPrintReceipt">
        <RECEIPT type="merchant" format="xml">
            <![CDATA[<RECEIPT>
    <AUTH_CODE>06130</AUTH_CODE>
    <CARD_SCHEME>VISA</CARD_SCHEME>
    <CURRENCY_CODE>GBP</CURRENCY_CODE>
    <CUSTOMER_PRESENCE>internet</CUSTOMER_PRESENCE>
    <FINAL_AMOUNT>1.00</FINAL_AMOUNT>
    <MERCHANT_NUMBER>8888888</MERCHANT_NUMBER>
    <PAN_NUMBER>454420******0382</PAN_NUMBER>
    <PAN_EXPIRY>12/15</PAN_EXPIRY>
    <TERMINAL_ID>04176421</TERMINAL_ID>
    <TOKEN>454420bbbbbkqrm0382</TOKEN>
    <TOTAL_AMOUNT>1.00</TOTAL_AMOUNT>
    <TRANSACTION_DATA_SOURCE>keyed</TRANSACTION_DATA_SOURCE>
    <TRANSACTION_DATE>14/02/2014</TRANSACTION_DATE>
    <TRANSACTION_NUMBER>000001</TRANSACTION_NUMBER>
    <TRANSACTION_RESPONSE>06130</TRANSACTION_RESPONSE>
    <TRANSACTION_TIME>17:13:17</TRANSACTION_TIME>
    <TRANSACTION_TYPE>purchase</TRANSACTION_TYPE>
    <VERIFICATION_METHOD>unknown</VERIFICATION_METHOD>
    <DUPLICATE>false</DUPLICATE>
</RECEIPT>]]>
        </RECEIPT>
    </INTERACTION>
</POI_MSG>
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/CDATASection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDATA is an encoding mechanism to include arbitrary data within an XML file.  Everything within CDATA is parsed as a single string when loading the XML into a `Document` instance.  If you need to access the contents of the CDATA as a DOM document, you will need to instantiate a second `Document` object from the string contents, make your changes, then serialize that back to a string and put the string back into a CDATA in the original document.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I agree this would be the best way forward (unfortunately I can't change the format of these messages as they are received from an external client). How would you suggest I extract the CDATA information? I will use the CharacterData.getData() function however I can't seem to find any way to locate the CDATA tag without checking every tag in the xml (via looping over all nodes).

i.e using doc.getElementByTagName("CDATA") doesn't seem to work.

Comment: CDATA is not a tag so you can't look for it that way.  You need to know the name of the containing tag.  From your example it looks like the attribute `format="xml"` will let you find tags containing XML, which is what you're looking for.  XPath would be `//*[@format='xml']`

Comment: Hey,

So I have written a function to find and extract the CDATA from this document. It is successfully retrieving the "RECEIPT" element and recognising that the child is CDATA, but then when I try and do cd.getData() on the character data, it gets the following:

[
,  ,  ,  ,  ]

(recognised as \n \t \t \t \t)

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think CDATA section will be parsed as other regular elements in the XML. CDATA section is purely to escape any syntax checks. My suggestion would be use a element to represent the data in CDATA section. If you still want to use CDATA section, I guess you'll need parse the section as a string and then load the data into a Document.